# REPEATABLE READ isolation level - successive SELECTs return different values

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I'm trying to check the REPEATABLE READ isolation level in PostgreSQL, specifically the statement:

> successive SELECT commands within a single transaction see the same
> data, i.e., they do not see changes made by other transactions that
> committed after their own transaction started.

To check that I run two scripts in two Query Editors in pg_admin.

The 1st one:

```
begin ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t2;

select * into t1 from topic where id=1;

select  pg_sleep(5);

select * into t2 from topic where id=1 ;

commit;
```

Here we have two successive *SELECT*s with the pause of 5 seconds between them, just to have time to run the 2nd *UPDATE* script. *t1* and *t2* are tables used to save the results. Thanks to them I'm able to check the selected data after the scripts execution.

I run the 2nd script immediately after the fist:

```
begin ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

 update topic set title='new value' where id=1;

commit;
```

It must commit after the 1st select but before the 2nd one.

The problem is that two successive *SELECT*s return *different* values - the results in *t1* and *t2* are different. I suggested they must the same. Could you explain me why this is happening?

Maybe *pg_sleep* starts transaction implicitly?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that - you must be making some mistake.

Comment: do you have the same results?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Yes, sorry,  I found very silly mistake - compare t1 and topic, not t1 and t2.